# How to validate Name in flutter?

Tags: regex, flutter, dart, validation

I want to allow only letter, space and dot(.) for Name filed input in a flutter project. No more than 5 spaces and 3 dots(.) will be allowed. How can I do that? I am new to programming, please help.

Comment: Please provide a code snippet what you have achieved so far.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please be aware this is not a free coding service. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the How to Ask page for details on how to best help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

I know there are some geniuses out there who can solve the above problem in Regex. But not everyone is a genius. I always solve these tough regex problems by creating a function for myself that does the same.

Take a look at the function below. It summarizes what I wanted to explain

```
bool validation(String a){
  
  int spaceNum = 0;
  int dotNum = 0;
  
  for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
    
    // check for valid characters
    if(!"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ .".contains(a[i])){
      return false;
    }
    
    // check for number of spaces
    if (a[i] == " "){
      spaceNum += 1;
      if (spaceNum > 5){
        return false;
      }
    }
    
    // check for number of dots
    if (a[i] == "."){
      dotNum += 1;
      if (dotNum > 3){
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  
  return true;
}

void main(){
  
  print(validation("Wrong.validation.      "));
  print(validation("Wrong....validation"));
  print(validation("Wrong1Validation12"));
  print(validation("Correct Validation..."));
 
}
```

The above returns the following results:
`false` (because the number of spaces is more than 5)
`false` (because the number of dots is more than 3)
`false` (because there is a digit instead of a letter)
`true`

Comment: You did it by writing your own programming without regex, great! But I am still looking for Regex. Thanks for helping.